# How much RAM I should assign to SQL Server 2008 running on W2K3

Tags: windows

I'm planning an installation for SQL 2008 over Windows 2003.  The server has 16g RAM. How much RAM I should assign to SQL server?

Comment: What other roles is the server going to be doing?

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit? Dedicated SQL Server?

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault?

Comment: This question belongs right here... it's a SQL Server Database configuration question. Just because the word server appears in the title does not mean it's a ServerFault question.

Answer (score 4):

12GB, leave 4GB for the OS.

This 12GB is for the various caches. The binaries and various out-of-process calls will use the 4GB, along with the OS.

Answer (score 2):

This is an overly broad question... you'll need to describe your load/throughput/etc requirements.

My gut reaction is to say "all of it."

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Try it on your SQL Server, allocate full RAM to SQL Server. See what happens.

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/08/24/troubleshooting-the-sql-server-memory-leak-or-understanding-sql-server-memory-usage.aspx